# Is it possible to use templates in Kate (KDE text editor)

Tags: kde, kate

I'm using Kate a lot to write bash scripts at work and we have agreed on a certain format (pretty long header with version info and changelog, pretty long comment before main part.

Is it possible to create a custom functionality in Kate where I could just create a new script starting with this Template?

Comment: [Kate Snippets](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/applications/kate/kate-application-plugin-snippets.html)

Comment: Exactly what I need. Mind putting an answer?

Comment: Answer added...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is it possible to create custom functionality where I create a new script?

You asked about templates. Kate does not have these but it does have a snippets plugin:

> Kate Snippets is a plugin used to save you some time by adding support for so-called “snippets” (re-usable source code, machine code or text). The plugin also supports code completion and JavaScript.
>
> - View → Tool Views → Show Snippets
>
>   Shows snippets panel containing all snippets in your repository that
>   are for the currently opened file type.
> - Tools → Create Snippet
>
>   Create a new snippet, which is a reusable chunk of text you may
>   insert in any part of any document.
>
> **Snippets panel**
>
> [image: Snippets panel]
>
> In the panel you should see a list of snippet repositories, along with
> options to create your own, get them from the Internet or load them
> from a local file. Each repository has a checkbox that can be used to
> activate or deactivate it. There are also buttons to edit and delete
> existing repositories.

Source: [Kate Snippets](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/applications/kate/kate-application-plugin-snippets.html)

The link above has additional instructions and screen shots.